# Qt5 - QWebEngine CORS for own uri type

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

So, the basic gist is, I have javascript resources like https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js that I use in the QWebEngine. The intention is, that the program also works offline, so I made a QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor that changes those addresses to my own local handler, in this case the target would be conapp://webresource/jquery.min.js

However, this results in this log message:

```
js: Redirect from 
'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js' has been 
blocked by CORS policy: Redirect location 
'conapp://webresource/jquery.min.js' has a disallowed scheme for cross-
origin requests.
```

Is there a way to allow redirects to conapp:// specifically?

Some Relevant Code Snippets, if it helps (PyQt5)

```
class Interceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Interceptor, self).__init__()
        QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile().setRequestInterceptor(self)

    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        url = info.requestUrl().toString()
        item = url.split("/")[-1]
        if item in LazyLoader:
            target = QUrl(r"conapp://webresource/{}".format(item))
            info.redirect(target)

class SchemeHandler(QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SchemeHandler, self).__init__()
        QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile().settings().setAttribute(6, True)
        QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile().installUrlSchemeHandler(b'conapp', self)
        self._handlers = {}

    def requestStarted(self, job):
        url = job.requestUrl()
        print("Got request for {}".format(url.toDisplayString()))
        request = url.toString().split("//")[1]

        buf = QBuffer(parent=self)
        buf.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        buf.write(self._handlers[request]().encode("utf-8"))
        buf.seek(0)
        buf.close()
        job.reply(b"text/html", buf)

    def register(self, contentgenerator, contentname):
        self._handlers[contentname] = contentgenerator
        return contentname
```

Comment: Would this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362212/qt-webview-intercept-loading-of-js-css-libraries-to-load-local-ones/49562170#49562170

Comment: No, because even other applications running on the same machine are not allowed to access. I've now implemented my own way of intercepting urls - by modifying the html, which is a workaround nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Combining with [Qt WebView - intercept loading of JS/CSS Libraries to load local ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362212/qt-webview-intercept-loading-of-js-css-libraries-to-load-local-ones/49562170#49562170)

Using a custom handler to allow the cross site access works for me

```
class Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    DATA_DIR = '/my_data_dir'
    def end_headers (self):
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        super().end_headers()
    def translate_path(self, path):
        return os.path.join(self.DATA_DIR, path.lstrip('/'))
```